# Displaying the database details in a specific design using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fetching the data from two tables question and answer and trying to display in a particular panel box.The problem I'm getting in this code is that the panel's size in which the data is displayed is decreasing with every single row of the database.
I'm using for loop to get the data Is it correct?

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'trialdvhub'); 
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$sql="SELECT * FROM question ";
$aResult=mysql_query($sql);
$sqli="SELECT * FROM answer";
$anresult=mysql_query($sqli);

?>
<?php
            $question = array();

            while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($aResult))
            { 
                $added       = $rows['added_by'];
                $date          = $rows['added_on'];
                $question[]      = $rows['description'];
            }
            ?>

            <?php
                $answer =array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($anresult))
                {
                    $answer[]= $row['description'];
            ?>

         <?php
            for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
            {
            ?>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">            
      <div class="panel-body"><img src="images\15.jpg" class="img-circle" style="width:20px;height:20px;"> 
       <span style="color:#949494;font-size:9;"><?php echo $added?> </span> <span style="color:#949494;font-size:9;"><?php echo $date?> </span>
      <p><h6><?php echo $question[$i]?></h6></p>
      <p><h6><span style="color:#949494"><?php echo $answer[$i]?></span></h6></p>
       <h6><span style="color:#949494">Share 35</span><img src="images\02.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.5cm;"><img src="images\03.ico" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.1cm;"><img src="images\04.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.1cm;"> <img src="images\b.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;"><span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Write your post</a></span><img src="images\07.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;"><span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;">26 Answered</span><img src="images\08.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;"><span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;">52 Views</span></h6>      
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
            <?php }?>           
          <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-1">
          </div>
                 </div>  
                     </div>
                         </div>
                         </div>                     
 <br>            
<hr>
</br>    
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-1">
         </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by panel's size is decreasing? Can you put screenshot so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: I'm putting the screen shots here

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not allowed to embed pictures becoz I'm new to the site

Comment: Panel that is a box like structure in which data is shown everytime the loop is fetching a data and displaying it in that box the size of that box is decreasing

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to not include your connection in the view and include a template layer. Look at PHP the right way for a start: http://www.phptherightway.com/#templating and also perhaps [look at a framework](https://github.com/codeguy/php-the-right-way/wiki/Frameworks)

Second thing would be to use the [alternate syntax for if/for/etc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and sort out your indentation (also learn about valid HTML as nesting h6 inside p tags is not correct). Once you indent correctly it's much easier to see that your outside `div`s are not all closed off within the loop so you are nesting rows in your loop which is why they get smaller every time.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<6;$i++): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">            
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="images\15.jpg" class="img-circle" style="width:20px;height:20px;"> 
                        <span style="color:#949494;font-size:9;"><?php echo $added?> </span>
                        <span style="color:#949494;font-size:9;"><?php echo $date?> </span>
                        <p><h6><?php echo $question[$i]?></h6></p>
                        <p><h6><span style="color:#949494"><?php echo $answer[$i]?></span></h6></p>
                        <h6>
                            <span style="color:#949494">Share 35</span>
                            <img src="images\02.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.5cm;">
                            <img src="images\03.ico" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.1cm;">
                            <img src="images\04.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:0.1cm;">
                            <img src="images\b.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;">
                            <span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Write your post</a></span>
                            <img src="images\07.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;">
                            <span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;">26 Answered</span>
                            <img src="images\08.png" class="img-circle" 
       style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:1cm;">
                            <span style="color:#949494;margin-left:0.3cm;">52 Views</span>
                        </h6>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
</div>                      
<br>             
<hr>
</br>    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
```

There are some other things you should look at, like LIMIT statements in your SQL to only pull back the data you need (at the minute you are pulling back all rows but only ever displaying the first 6).